# longtable and rowcolors

Tags: longtable

I tried to use the longtable with the row color and I just simply can get it to work. When I try to do:

```
\documentclass[10pt, landscape]{report}
    %Packages
        \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
        \usepackage[english, ngerman]{babel}
        \usepackage{booktabs}
        \usepackage{array}
            \newcounter{rowno}
            \setcounter{rowno}{0}
        \usepackage{longtable}
        \usepackage[table]{xcolor}  
    \begin{document} 
    \rowcolors{1}{gray!40!white}{blue!10!white} 
            \begin{longtable}{>{\stepcounter{rowno}\therowno.}c c l c l l l l }
            \hiderowcolors
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{No.} & Article & Word & Type & 3. Person & Präteritum & Perfect & Translation \\
            \toprule
            \endfirsthead
            \showrowcolors
            \hiderowcolors
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{No.} & Article & Word & Type & 3. Person & Präteritum & Perfect & Translation \\
            \toprule 
            \endhead
            \showrowcolors
            & --- & abdecken & verb & deckt ab & deckte ab & abgedeckt & to cover, \\ \midrule
            & --- & abholen & verb & holt ab & holte ab & abgeholte & to collect or pick up \\ \midrule 
    \end{longtable}
    \end{document}
```

I am getting every row to be the same color - gray. I tried doing different things with it but to no avail.

[image]

Did anyone dealt with something like that and have a solution?

Comment: give a _complete_ example which shows what you see

Comment: The `\stepcounter{rowno}\therowno` gives an automatic count to the rows in the table (there are ~240 entries in it)

Answer (score 3):

it is a problem with your setting of `\show/hiderowcolors`. This works:

```
\documentclass[10pt, landscape]{report}
    %Packages
        \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
        \usepackage[english, ngerman]{babel}
        \usepackage{booktabs}
        \usepackage{array}
            \newcounter{rowno}
            \setcounter{rowno}{0}
        \usepackage{longtable}
        \usepackage[table]{xcolor}  
    \begin{document} 
    \rowcolors{3}{gray!40!white}{blue!40!white!80} 
            \begin{longtable}{>{\stepcounter{rowno}\therowno.}c c l c l l l l }
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{No.} & Article & Word & Type & 3. Person & Präteritum & Perfect & Translation \\\toprule
            \endfirsthead
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{No.} & Article & Word & Type & 3. Person & Präteritum & Perfect & Translation \\
            \toprule 
            \endhead
            & --- & abdecken & verb & deckt ab & deckte ab & abgedeckt & to cover, \\
            & --- & abholen & verb & holt ab & holte ab & abgeholte & to collect or pick up\\             & --- & abholen & verb & holt ab & holte ab & abgeholte & to collect or pick up\\             & --- & abholen & verb & holt ab & holte ab & abgeholte & to collect or pick up\\ \bottomrule 
    \end{longtable}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Actually it appears that `\midrule` was the problem. When I removed the \show/hidecolors I got nowhere fast, however after removing the `\midrule' everything works fine

Answer (score 0):

Actually it appears that `\midrule` was the problem. When I removed the \show/hidecolors I got nowhere fast, however after removing the `\midrule` everything works fine